# Bind input value to specific value in object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to build a timesheet application where users can enter the amount of hours they are working each day. I'm storing the data about each user in an object and I wish to populate an input field in a table with each respective hour (`duration`). To illustrate how I want to store the data, I added an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUHUx.jpg

And also a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h64wafkp/14/

Basically, each user in the database has a one-to-many relationship with another table called "hours", so the data structure looks as such:

```
 {
"id": 1,
"firstname": "JayZ",
"lastname": "Carter",
"email": "jay@rocafella.com",
"hours": [
  {
    "id": 226,
    "user_id": 1,
    "date": "2018-12-05",
    "duration": 140
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "date": "2018-12-02",
    "duration": 13
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "user_id": 1,
    "date": "2018-12-03",
    "duration": 13
  }
]
```

},

Then there's the table itself which is just a regular html table with each respective day as column headers. My issue is how to bind each `duration` to each respective date cell (see image above). Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to find a way to bind those hours' object values. The issue is that you're using an array of objects, with dates inside that object. The way to link the correct time object using the date as a key is inefficient (requires n^2). There's also no guarantee that there is only one entry per date. I think it would be worthwhile figuring out that particular piece, otherwise the function to support this schema may be too complex.

Comment: Any idea how I could do it? Been stuck on this for the last 4 months or so.. would be great if there was a library/ui component for this. Unfortunately I can't find a datatable for this type of behavior

Comment: There likely isn't one. It seems to me like an issue with the schema. if you restrict it to a single entry per date (per user). you could use the date as a key. You can also set up a computed to figure this out for existing entries, but it won't be able to add new values just using `bind`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `methods` define a function to get the duration for a given user and date:

```
getDuration(user_id, date) {
    const user = this.users.find(user => user.id == user_id);
    const hour = user.hours.find(hour => hour.date == date);
    return hour ? hour.duration : 0;
},
```

Then in the HTML part add a `:value` attribute to the `input` element:

```
:value="getDuration(user.id, day)"
```

If you need to also bind *updates* to those input values back to the data structure, you'll need to define a function `setDuration` and call it with the following `input` attribute:

```
@input="e => setDuration(user.id, day, e.target.value)"
```

You would again locate the user and hour as above, but then you need to possibly add an hour object to the `hours` array, where you need a new id. I don't know how you would generate new id values in your case, so I'll leave that for you to implement (see comment):

```
setDuration(user_id, date, duration) {
    const user = this.users.find(user => user.id == user_id);
    const hour = user.hours.find(hour => hour.date == date);
    if (hour) {
        hour.duration = duration;
    } else {
        user.hours.push({
            id: getNewId(), // <--- implement this!
            user_id,
            date,
            duration
        });
    }
},
```

After our exchange below it turns out that your ORM will recognise an hour record needs to be *inserted* (instead of updated) if there is no `id` property, so in that case just omit the line:

```
            id: getNewId(), // <--- implement this!
```

Comment: Regarding the `setDuration`. part. I'm sending all my data to a postgres db through my rest api. The update/insert function can accept two different structures, either by providing an id (hour id) or user_id. Basically like this: https://imgur.com/a/g2YAfx3

If the first object is sent (with `id`), it'll update an existing hour row with id `181` and if I provide a `user_id`, it'll post a new hour to the user that has an id of `12` and automatically asign it an id (auto incremented)

Comment: In that case you can omit the `id: getNewId()` line, and apply the appropriate logic where you send updates to your db, i.e. you choose the appropriate structure based on whether the `hour` object has an `id` property (= update) or not (=insert).

Comment: It works almost out of the box with your solution since I can actually send the data with both `id` and `user_id` - the ORM I'm using understands that it should update if both `id` and `user_id` are found. However, I tried adding a new object in my data property called `hoursToSubmit`
(which is just  equal to `user.hours` in `setDuration`) - The only thing is that if I add a value in an input field for user 1, and then another value for user 2, my `hoursToSubmit` only reflects the changes made for user 2 - can I use `$set` or something to store all inputs across all users?

Comment: This really is a new question. Could you post it as such and provide the object structure with that property, and explanation of the problem?

Comment: Sure - here's a short snippet of what I wish to achieve: https://vimeo.com/306271901
Essentially, I want all inputs across all rows saved so I can submit all to my database. Notice how the object with inputs only reflect the user that had the latest input changed

Comment: I don't mean you should post it as a *comment*, but as a new *question* (with the `Ask Question` button at the top-right) ;-)

Comment: Yeah I know, sorry, just wanted to clarify :D

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help by the way. Really appreciate it - can't believe you just whipped a solution out in like 5 minutes..